# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: maven, jsf, factory, illegalstateexception, embedded-tomcat-8

I have a JSF Web application and since i'm using using an embedded databse, i wanted to use an embedded server, so i went with tomcat.

I found a main class with the code i need.
I executed the main class using eclipse and everything worked fine so i decided to build to the project to a jar to execute it from the command line, and this is where this exception came up

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:555)
    javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:358)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the Main Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class Main {
  private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
  private final static String mWorkingDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
  private static Tomcat tomcat = null;

  public static Tomcat getTomcat() {
      if(tomcat == null)
          tomcat = new Tomcat();
      return tomcat;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(9090);
    tomcat.setBaseDir(mWorkingDir);
    tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(mWorkingDir);
    tomcat.getHost().setAutoDeploy(true);
    tomcat.getHost().setDeployOnStartup(true);

    try {
      tomcat.start();
    } catch (LifecycleException e) {
      LOGGER.severe("Tomcat could not be started.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOGGER.info("Tomcat started on " + tomcat.getHost());

    // Alternatively, you can specify a WAR file as last parameter in the following call e.g. "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\app.war"
    Context appContext = tomcat.addWebapp(tomcat.getHost(), "/JsfWebProject", "A:\\JsfWebProject.war");
    LOGGER.info("Deployed " + appContext.getBaseName() + " as " + appContext.getBaseName());

    tomcat.getServer().await();
  }
}
```

The Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>webProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>JsfWebProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.sopra.util.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JSF libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Java Mail API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2Database library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.179</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache poi and Xml related libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ChartistJSF library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.chartistjsf</groupId>
            <artifactId>ChartistJSF</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Primefaces Exporter Pluguin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lapis.jsfexporter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-exporter-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lapis.jsfexporter</groupId>
            <artifactId>export-type-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lapis.jsfexporter</groupId>
            <artifactId>export-type-excel</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lapis.jsfexporter</groupId>
            <artifactId>export-type-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lapis.jsfexporter</groupId>
            <artifactId>export-type-xml</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lapis.jsfexporter</groupId>
            <artifactId>export-source-primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and The Web.cml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>JsfWebProject</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: The error message means that your application doesn't find the JSF implementation. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369903/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-find-backup-for-factory-javax-faces.

Comment: BTW, do you really need the jstl.jar?

Comment: perhaps i don't need the jstl jar, but as you can see in my pon, i have both the api and the implementation of JSF in my project

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and it puzzles me. Maybe your configuration is not found? Try to add some nonsense to your `faces-config.xml`, make it illegal XML, and see if anything changes. If nothing changes, your `faces-config.xml` isn't read at all, and this might be the problem. But I have to admit that this is a wide shot.