# Websphere 8.5.5 + JSF 2.2.7 Error

Tags: primefaces, axis, jsf-2.2, websphere-8

I got a JSF/Primefaces project working fine on tomcat 7, but when I open de login page on websphere application server 8.5.5 i got this following error. The application in Was8.5.5 is set to "Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)" and "Single class loader for application"

i'm using these jars:

axis.jar
common.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections-3.0.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-fileupload.jar
commons-validator.jar
groovy-all-2.0.1.jar
iText-2.1.7.js1.jar
jasperreports-5.5.2.jar
javax.faces-2.2.7.jar
jaxrpc.jar
jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar
jdom.jar
jsoup-1.7.3.jar
ojdbc5.jar
primefaces-5.0.jar
saaj.jar
ucp.jar
Util.jar
velocity-1.7-dep.jar
wcp.jar
wsdl4j.jar
xalan.jar
xstream-1.3.1.jar

Anyone could give some advise?

```
000000b6 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause Faces Servlet: javax.servlet.ServletException
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError
        at org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.initErrorPages(ConfigContainer.java:283)
        at org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.initConfigFromWebXml(ConfigContainer.java:260)
        at org.primefaces.config.ConfigContainer.<init>(ConfigContainer.java:84)
        at org.primefaces.context.DefaultApplicationContext.<init>(DefaultApplicationContext.java:35)
        at org.primefaces.context.DefaultRequestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultRequestContext.java:227)
        at org.primefaces.metadata.ComponentMetadataTransformerListener.processEvent(ComponentMetadataTransformerListener.java:40)
        at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
        at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(ComponentSystemEvent.java:118)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2163)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:303)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.publishAfterViewEvents(UIComponentBase.java:2246)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.doPostAddProcessing(UIComponentBase.java:1927)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setParent(UIComponentBase.java:447)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2680)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2652)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addComponent(ComponentSupport.java:489)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:350)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:333)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:222)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
        at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:174)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:990)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
        ... 26 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make websphere 8.5 use mojarra not myfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258561/how-to-make-websphere-8-5-use-mojarra-not-myfaces) Although a bit different also tells how to change JSF engine in WebSphere 8.5.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable built in JSF engine. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24260662/3701228) for more details. You have to configure isolated shared library and map it to the application.

Comment: Gas, Tanks for your replies, i think that the problem i'ts not the jsf libs, in fact i've removed the axis, jaxrpc and wsdl4j jars and the project is running well on WAS 8.5.5. But with these libs the app starts well but when the login page is called that error appears...

Comment: @FlávioDantasdeSouza Flavio `VerifyError` usually means that library was compiled using different JDK. Make sure you are using same JDK level. If on Tomcat you were using 1.7 you will need to update WAS to 1.7 as by default it is 1.6.

Comment: Both are 1.6. In the Project Facets and Java Compiler levels and also on websphere 8.5 Java SDKs. But I don't have JDK1.6 in my localhost: java version "1.7.0_04"
Would you think this is causing the error?

Comment: @FlávioDantasdeSouza Have you tried solution with isolated shared library? Or removing `javax.faces-2.2.7.jar` from the jars?

Comment: Done, i just replaced the application "jaxrpc.jar" with "javax.j2ee.jaxrpc.jar" from native ibm websphere 8.5.5 implementation. 

Thanks again Gas!