# Primefaces 5.2 + WebSphere 8.5.5.9 - Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, websphere

I'm trying to run the [Primeface's Showcase sample application](https://github.com/primefaces/showcase) on WebSphere 8.5.5.9 Full profile.

I've already configured the application to use the correct JSF library (javax.faces-2.2.8.jar), following these steps:

- [How to make websphere 8.5 use mojarra not myfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258561/how-to-make-websphere-8-5-use-mojarra-not-myfaces/24260662#24260662)
- [Upgrading Mojarra in IBM WebSphere 8.5](http://wittakarn.blogspot.com.br/2014/09/upgrading-mojarra-in-ibm-websphere-85.html)

Now, I'm getting the following statcktrace (the full stack trace can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.ca/3602187)):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.
     at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:500)
     at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:287)
     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:350)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:344)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:636)
   ...
```

[See full stack trace](http://pastebin.ca/3602187)

Comment: Exception tells that the runtime classpath is polluted with multiple different versioned JSF libraries conflicting each other. Apparently configuring JSF library went wrong.

Comment: Thank for the comment, but it's a new server installation, there are no other applications deployed than the Showcase. I've configured the application build to not include the shared library (as provided). Do you know if I need to remove some file from the server?

Comment: So, I've managed to get this thing working (sort of, at least). Besides the shared library for JSF, I've configured all the dependencies as "provided", and then configured a shared library on WAS with all commons* jars which previously where on my WAR. 
Apparently, that is the way to go with WebSphere, I'll keep configuring shared libs until everything is working.