# Having exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/w3c/dom/Node.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String while startup of application in websphere

Tags: java, websphere, war, startup

I installed an application (WAR file) on Websphere Application Server (8.0.0.12).

**When I start the application i got the following exception:**

```
[9/13/16 14:27:07:756 CEST] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context '/ihuborg_V'
[9/13/16 14:27:21:935 CEST] 0000000e FfdcProvider W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs/ffdc/eom-client-dist-s2_f4fbf9c1_16.09.13_14.27.21.853564311419988705074.txt com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated 1341
[9/13/16 14:27:21:937 CEST] 0000000e webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0} java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/w3c/dom/Node.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.getNodeText(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:140)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.processFactories(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:125)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:203)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1693)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1167)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2176)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5480)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5606)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2181)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:496)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1731)

[9/13/16 14:27:22:758 CEST] 0000000e webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0} javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:406)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1368)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:621)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:590)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:421)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1167)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2176)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5480)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5606)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2181)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:496)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1731)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized
    at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:725)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:239)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:344)
    ... 28 more
```

WebSphere:cuname=eom-client-dist-s2 in BLA WebSphere:blaname=eom-client-dist-s2 started.

**ENVIRONMENT DETAILS:**

Java version: -bash-4.2$ /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java -version java version "1.6.0" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6460_26sr8fp15ifix-20151124_01(SR8 FP15+IV79094)) IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.6.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20151019_272772 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) J9VM - R26_Java626_SR8_20151019_2248_B272772

**WAS installed on Platform:** Linux x86_64

**Class-Loading policy:**

[image]

[image]
**Note:** Same application is running fine in other environment.

Please help me what could be the reason and solution to above problem.

Comment: It seems that some of your applications are running different versions of the same component. The JVM loads only one copy into the memory, so it can't find the specific method.

Comment: Your application may contain different JSF implementation. Check [third party JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24258561/how-to-make-websphere-8-5-use-mojarra-not-myfaces/24260662#24260662)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that multiple versions of class org/w3c/dom/Node is available in class path.  Recreate the problem by enabling verbose class (add - verbose:class to Java command line options),  which gives you the jar location from where org/w3c/dom/Node is loaded.